# Change cloud service region

Tags: azure

Is it possible to change a Cloud Service region (i.e: move from East US to West US)?

I don't see an option from the management console to do it or maybe I did not dig deep enough.

I would like to do it since I have my database in one region different to my application's and I guess it could decrease performance.

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no way to change Cloud Service region. You have to create new Cloud Service in desired region and redeploy there. It becomes more complicated when you also have Storage accounts with data which you have to move. For this you could probably use [Red Gate's Cloud Services](http://cloudservices.red-gate.com/Home/Features#storageBackup) or other mature product.

And you are right about Database and performance. It is not only performance, but also costs savings. When your Database is in different geographic region all data that comes out of your database is basically Outbound (Egress) traffic, which is being charged per GB!

Comment: I have written code to migrate data from your Table Storage and your Blobs from one storage account to another if your need it : http://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2013/06/20/windows-azure-table-storage-service-migrating-tables-between-storage-accounts/

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own script using Powershell that is a powerful tool and can help you a lot, including copying the data between regions directly (not passing by your computer). I am going to do that know.